# Just run into a strange notation ... what can the result of it be? What could be the programming language?

Tags: linux

```
©¹⁶C¹⁶®  ©⁺⏻⁺®  ©⁴2⁴®  ©⁺÷⁺®  ©¹⁰2¹⁰®
```

I have trouble to guess what will this expression most likely evaluate to. Any ideas?

Here further sample of code:

```
©ₛxₛ® ©<->® ©¹⁶ff¹⁶® ©;® ©ₛyₛ® ©<->® ©¹⁰128¹⁰®  ©;®  ©® 
©ₛzₛ® ©<->® ©ₛxₛ® ©⁺+⁺® ©ₛyₛ® ©;® ©®
```

### UPDATE considering the up-to-now comments:

Hmmm ... this question assumes a little bit of thought and probably some experience with designing custom programming languages.

I have confronted ChatGPT with the question and got following response:

**user**
`©¹⁶D¹⁶®  ©⁺⏻⁺®  ©⁴2⁴®  ©⁺=⁺®  ©¹⁰169¹⁰®` ?

**ChatGPT**
Let's analyze the expression:

- `©¹⁶D¹⁶®`: This segment compares something to the hexadecimal value `13`.
- `©⁺⏻⁺®`: This segment involves raising the result of the third segment to the power of the result of the fourth segment.
- `©⁴2⁴®`: This segment compares something to the base-4 value `66`, which translates to decimal `2` in base 4.
- `©⁺=⁺®`: This segment involves incrementing by one, which means adding `1`.
- `©¹⁰169¹⁰®`: This segment compares something to the decimal value `169`.

Now let's evaluate each part:

- The first segment evaluates to the hexadecimal value `13`.
- The third segment evaluates to decimal `2`.
- The fourth segment involves comparing the result of the up-to-now evaluation to the number to its right.
- Therefore, the result of the second segment is `13` raised to the power of `2`, which equals `169`.
- The fifth segment evaluates to decimal `169`.

So, the expression compares `169` to `169` using the equality operation, which results in `True`. Therefore, the evaluation of the expression would be `True`.

---

It's sure not perfect and partly just wrong, but still better than the up to now responses here on stackoverflow ...

---

> Let me repeat your original question. "dQw4w9WgXcQ What will this evaluate to?". I literally took your initial post and changed the > code string. I have stock chrome as my browser, so  > if that doesn't understand what you tried to post > you need to post it some other way if you want > people to understand it – Gabe Sechan

Hmmm ... Below a screenshot from the history:

[image: History - Original Posting]

Anyone else who has experienced similar problem as reported by *Gabe Sechan* ? Without more information about it I am not able to know what and why went wrong in order to make it next time better. We are living in an age of Unicode ... so I can surely assume that accessing stackoverflow with ASCII terminals showing weird results on Unicode is not what needs to be considered while posting a question ...

Comment: @GillesQuénot : what did you want to say with your comment? I can't get the message ...

Comment: Without the programming language nobody knows.  It's some esoteric joke language similar to brainfuck, not something actually used.

Comment: @GabeSechan : I suppose that this is an attempt of using  the potential of Unicode to overcome some deficiencies of available programming languages which limit themselves to the ASCII range. In my eyes it would make sense to try to grasp the idea behind it. Brainfuck is useless ... but this seems to be something which could be really more useful as the available languages are.

Comment: Lots of available languages **don't** limit themselves to the ASCII range. You can use many Unicode characters in variable names in lots of languages. I think Gilles tried to explain this. Your snippet could be from any language that supports Unicode and that syntax so it's not really likely you'll get an answer to this question. (Most of the "syntax" here is actually just non-reserved unicode characters)

Comment: @Romen : which of available languages don't limit themselves to the ASCII range? The mainstream does ... Any hints?

Comment: C++, C#, Java, Javascript, and Python all support  "letter-like" Unicode characters in identifiers. These are all "mainstream" languages IMO. I guess some of the characters in the snippet in your question are not "letter-like", I didn't look up their Unicode attributes.

Comment: @Romen : yes, letter-like, but ... not any free Unicode text with spaces, tabs and line feeds within the identifier/symbol/variable name. The only language which indirectly supports "identifier" which can be any Unicode text is shell scripting. To make use of it you need to work with files instead of environment variables - this opens a fully new world of possibilities ...

Comment: Or lets go to the granddaddy of non-ascii languages, APL.  Which used a lot of mathematical notation and required a special keyboard to write.  It's not a new idea.

Comment: @GabeSechan : the chars used in the code above are  available by default on my `English US intl. with dead keys` keyboard I use on my Linux Mint 21 Xfce box. And yes, I know about APL ... I have written applications in it decades ago ... but the basic idea is different - it makes in my eyes no sense to compare to APL here ... I suggest you try to invest some time in understanding the difference in order to see clearly the potential behind the in the code snippet above demonstrated concept if consequently applied to programming. The final goal is to use natural English for coding ...

Comment: You posted a ranfdom series of characters with no explanation and no context.  There's no potential because there's nothing to explain what you were trying to accomplish.  And if you're looking for ideas or opinions on a new programming language-  that's far off topic here.

Comment: @GabeSechan : sorry ... I feel not responsible for your point of view and resistance to understanding. The question is a very clear one: you have code and you want to understand what it does. Most of the questions here on stackoverflow are exactly the same kind. And it is just not true that I have posted a random series of characters with no explanation and no context ...

Comment: @GabeSechan : by the way: ChatGPT was able to ask for further details and to come up with an interpretation and with some help also with a correct result. Not sure if it would be possible to teach it the syntax of this language to the degree it understands Python, but with appropriate amount of commented code it appears quite possible.

Comment: @GabeSechan : have you ever tried to create an own kind of programming language which differs from the mainstream? Like for example Rebol?

Comment: Let me repeat your original question.  "dQw4w9WgXcQ  What will this evaluate to?"  There is no context there.  We don't know thius language you're making, the concepts behind it, or anything else.  It would be like trying to guess the meaning of a phrase of linear B.  I know what that string is, and you know what yours is.  But nobody else in the world could possibly guess it (Ok, mine makes sense if you search for it on youtube)

Comment: @GabeSechan : Hmmm ... I haven't changed anything in my question since first upload except adding further text - so what you had experienced has maybe something to do with the browser you are using? I assume that nowadays anyone uses Unicode aware Internet browser and has the appropriate fonts installed (stackoverflow should care about that, doesn't it?). ... Just checked out history ... You can see that the issue isn't there on my side ... right?

Comment: I literally took your initial post and changed the code string.  I have stock chrome as my browser, so if that doesn't understand what you tried to post you need to post it some other way if you want people to understand it

Comment: But to be clear what I see is something like copyright symbol to the 16th power C to the 16th power registered symbol space copyright symbol + power symbol...   so broken unicode does make sense here.  Except that does seem to match your answer, in which case, yeah your question needs several pages of context to make sense

Comment: The Copyright Symbol ... is like the < in an HTML Tag ... You could criticize HTML in the same way: what you see is less than comparisons not tags ... There are myriads of ways to consider something being useless or having no sense ... but only few ways to make the right use of the right tools. If ChatGPT can get the idea right ... am I expecting too much from an intelligent human to get the idea too? Programming languages are very similar to each other ... if you see FFA7 ... you know it is hex code ... if you see 1874 its probably decimal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about 72? The code suggests numbers in given base and the Unicode power symbol suggests exponentiation ...

Here my interpretation of the code:

- the © and ® are used to enclose a unit of meaning which context is given by the superscript part and the value by the other part
- superscript 16, 4 and 10 are hints towards the base in which given digits of a number need to be interpreted. The C means in this context decimal 12, the 2 in base 4 is 2 and the 2 in base 10 means also decimal two.
- The superscript plus sign seems to be a hint towards interpretation of the tag content as an arithmetic operator. The Unicode POWER SIGN suggests that the operator is exponentiation and the division sign suggests division

Considering all of the above the code translates to:

`12 ^ 2 / 2`

which results in 72.

---

Considering the further code you have provided I guess that the programming language will support any Unicode text as names of variables and make parsing much easier because the interpretation of the code is already given by what can be seen as similar to HTML tags.

It appears that if this is the concept of the language there will be no need to mark comments in the code and any text in between and any whitespace will stay without impact on the executed code. It is just inside-out or upside-down: the code is what is marked and the comment areas don't contrary to what is the case in all of the programming languages known to me up to now.

```
©ₛxₛ® ©<->® ©¹⁶ff¹⁶® ©;® ©ₛyₛ® ©<->® ©¹⁰128¹⁰®  ©;®  ©® 
©ₛzₛ® ©<->® ©ₛxₛ® ©⁺+⁺® ©ₛyₛ® ©;® ©®
```

My interpretation of the above is that subscript `s` suggests a symbol name, and `©<->®` function is similar to assignment, but the arrows in both directions indicate the possibility to find the symbol name given the value. The plus sign embedded in superscript plus ones indicate addition, so considering all of the above the code is equivalent to:

```
x=255 ; y=128 ;
z=x+y ;
```

The advantage here could be that assuming the guess is right it should be possible to write the code as follows:

> Let us assign to the symbol named x: ©ₛxₛ® ©<->® the value 255 defined in hexadecimal notation ©¹⁶ff¹⁶® ©;® and let us assign to the symbol y ©ₛyₛ® ©<->® the value of ©¹⁰128¹⁰®  ©;®  ©® . Now let the variable named z ©ₛzₛ® ©<->® be calculated as as sum of ©ₛxₛ® ©⁺+⁺® and ©ₛyₛ® ©;® ©® which will be 383 .

The text above would be a valid code as there is no need to mark comments. This way any Unicode text and any deliberate formatting of the text becomes possible without the interpreter complaining about wrong format.

Another advantage of this way of coding would be to make it much easier for code parser to identify the parts which needs styling as the information about what is what is already given and need not to be guessed from some kind of lexing according to given set of language syntax rules.